# Differential operator has changed into another one of laplacian operator. How this change occured?

Tags: vector-spaces, laplacian

$$
\begin{align}
\text{Given equation}~:\nabla^2\mathbf E&={\partial\mathbf E\over\partial\mathrm{t}}+{\partial^2\mathbf E\over\partial\mathrm{t^2}}~~\text{where}~~E_z=0\\
\text{Equation which I can't understand now}~:{\partial^2 E_x\over\partial\mathrm{z^2}}&={\partial E_x\over\partial\mathrm{t}}+{\partial^2 E_x\over\partial\mathrm{t^2}}
\end{align}
$$

[The book](https://www.amazon.co.jp/%E8%A9%B3%E8%A7%A3%E9%9B%BB%E7%A3%81%E6%B0%97%E5%AD%A6%E6%BC%94%E7%BF%92-%E5%BE%8C%E8%97%A4-%E6%86%B2%E4%B8%80/dp/4320030222/ref=pd_lpo_2?pd_rd_i=4320030222&psc=1&asin=4320030222&revisionId=&format=4&depth=1) says that second equation can be obtained taking$~x,y~$axes such that$~E_x,H_y~$only remain with direction of proceed is taken to$~z~$axis.

Currently I can't comprehend this statement.

So in the first place with my memory of def of laplacian operator, the eqn1 is completely same as following equation.

$$\left({\partial^2 E_x\over\partial\mathrm{x^2}},{\partial^2 E_y\over\partial\mathrm{y^2}},{\partial^2E_z\over\partial\mathrm{z^2}}\right)=\left({\partial E_x\over\partial\mathrm{t}},{\partial E_y\over\partial\mathrm{t}},{\partial E_z\over\partial\mathrm{t}}\right)+\left({\partial^2 E_x\over\partial\mathrm{t^2}},{\partial^2 E_y\over\partial\mathrm{t^2}},{\partial^2E_z\over\partial\mathrm{t^2}}\right)\tag{1}$$

So the eqn2 is relavent with the first element of the vector above, that is

$${\partial E_x\over\partial\mathrm{x^2}}={\partial E_x\over\partial\mathrm{t}}+{\partial^2 E_x\over\partial\mathrm{t^2}}\tag{2}$$

Why$~z~$can be replaced for$~x~$?

**ADD**

I thought that coefficients of original equation is needless here so I removed it above and I wrote down the true given equations in the book.

$$\nabla^2 \mathbf E=\epsilon\mu{\partial^2 \mathbf E\over\partial\mathrm{t^2}}+\sigma\mu{\partial \mathbf E\over\partial\mathrm{t}}$$

$$  {\partial^2 E_x\over\partial\mathrm{z^2}}=\sigma\mu{\partial E_x\over\partial\mathrm{t}}+\epsilon\mu{\partial^2 E_x\over\partial\mathrm{t^2}} $$

And the solution for the above equation is as follows.

$$  E_x=E_0 \exp\left(- \sqrt{\mu\sigma\omega/2}z  \right) \cos\left(\omega t - \sqrt{\mu\sigma\omega/2} z  \right)  $$

Comment: Which book ? Is the second equation not just the $x$-component of the first equation ?

Comment: Are you sure about your definition of the 'vector Laplacian'? See the relevant section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator#:~:text=Vector%20Laplacian,-The%20vector%20Laplace&text=%2C%20is%20a%20differential%20operator%20defined,field%2C%20returning%20a%20vector%20quantity. Namely, shouldn't the entries of the vector Laplacian be the Laplacian of the individual entries? So I think your equation (1) might be incorrect.

Comment: And I removed your 'cartesian-closed categories' tag - it has little to do with your question.

Comment: @KurtG.
The book is not written in English. . . 

The original equation for the first equation is following of telegraph equation. And about$~\mathbf{E}_{}~$,only the x-component of partial differentation is written there. 

$${\partial^2 E_x\over\partial\mathrm{z^2}}=\epsilon\mu{\partial^2 E_x\over\partial\mathrm{t^2}}+\sigma\mu{\partial E_x\over\partial\mathrm{t}}$$

I removed $~\epsilon,\mu,\sigma~$from the original equation since one may feel time-taking to write these coefficients.

Comment: Sorry. "first" in the last message mine should be $\color{red}{\text{second}}$

Comment: @peterag Yes, it might be...

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

As far as I can tell you are asking how the equations
\begin{align}
{\partial^2 E_x\over\partial\mathrm{z^2}}&={\partial E_x\over\partial\mathrm{t}}+{\partial^2 E_x\over\partial\mathrm{t^2}}\,,\\
{\partial^2 E_y\over\partial\mathrm{z^2}}&={\partial E_y\over\partial\mathrm{t}}+{\partial^2 E_y\over\partial\mathrm{t^2}}\,,\\
{\partial^2 E_z\over\partial\mathrm{z^2}}&={\partial E_z\over\partial\mathrm{t}}+{\partial^2 E_z\over\partial\mathrm{t^2}}
\end{align}
follow from
\begin{align}
\nabla^2\mathbf E&={\partial\mathbf E\over\partial\mathrm{t}}+{\partial^2\mathbf E\over\partial\mathrm{t^2}}
\end{align}
when --as your book seems to say-- $E_x,E_y,E_z$ only depend on $z$.

- This is totally trivial as $\mathbf{E}$ is the vector $(E_x,E_y,E_z)$.
- Unfortunately you have not answered my question what book that exactly is which is why I am now voting to close your question.